# Azure Service Fabric deployment - A Virtual Machine is not available in the region to service your Request

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

We are getting the below warning in the VSTS release page and it is taking more than an hour to complete the deployment. What should be the workaround for this?

> A Virtual Machine is not available in West Europe to service your Request right now, your Request is being assigned to a Virtual Machine in Central US. You may experience slower execution than normal during certain phases of your Build or Release. For example, downloading source code or build artifacts may be slower than usual during this Request.

Comment: Are you building/deploying a new cluster or trying to deploy the SF application on azure cluster ?

Comment: What's the region of your VSTS (https://{account}.visualstudio.com/_admin/_home/settings)? There is the related issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/171563/getting-a-virtual-machine-is-not-available-in-west.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider creating one or more Virtual Machines (e.g. [B-series](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-b-series-our-new-burstable-vm-size/)):

- Install the [Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows) (configured to run as a service or daemon)
- Add prerequistites (.NET Fx /dotnet core, SF SDK)
- Configure backup
- Use this from your pipeline.

This way you'll have faster builds and releases.